# Change color of a word in a text entry area?

Tags: php, input, colors, textarea, cpu-word

I'm currently working on a website with questions/responses and I have a problem. I have a word in :

> $first_word

and this textarea :

```
$answer .= '<div rel="tooltip-forced" title="'.$answertooltip.'"><textarea x-speech="true" class="textarea' . $kpclass . "\" $readonly type=\"text\" placeholder=\"votre réponse\" size=\"$tiwidth\" name=\"$ia[1]\" " . "id=\"answer{$ia[1]}\" rows=\"" . $drows . "\" cols=\"" . $tiwidth . "\" maxlength=\"" . $maxsize . "\" " . $readonly . " >" . $answer_content . "</textarea></div></div>";
```

. On

> $answer_content

in the textarea I have a sentence that I have wrote previously and that appear again in the textarea after I submit with a button. What I want is a way to color the word in

> $first_word

after the submit. I know that it's not possible with textarea, so is their another way to get what I want ? Thanks :)

Comment: You can for example use  a `div` with the attribute `contenteditable`, then you can apply HTML/CSS styling. Get the contents with Javascript and post it.

Comment: You may want to try something like html area or tinyMCE (or any other editor of your choice), as these should enable that sort of markup in a user input type of control without the headache of coding it all up yourself.